# Converting .bat to .ps1 to automate vbs to run SAS EG reports

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript

I currently use a series of .bat files to automate my SAS EG reports every morning so that by the time I get in, the data is already there and I can start working. .bat files are creating security issues with our new Windows 10 platform, so we were asked to convert our .bat files to .ps1.  i'm having trouble translating the syntax so that I have the same functionality (reports have to run consecutively, not concurrently)

I have a reference book that I've been using, but it's not detailed enough (Microsoft PowerShell, VBScript, and JScript Bible by Stanek, O'Neill, Rosen)

original .bat code:

```
@echo off
rem This batch script executes multiple VB scripts

echo Executing Daily4

echo %time% Running Report1
cscript //nologo //E:vbscript "\\[FOLDER LOCATION]\EGScript43.vbs"
echo %time% Finished Running Report1

echo %time% Running Report2
cscript //nologo //E:vbscript "\\[FOLDER LOCATION]\PUMA_Check.vbs"
echo %time% Finished Running Report2

echo All jobs complete
```

Attempted .ps1 code:

```
Write-Progress -Activity "Running Report1" -SecondsRemaining;
Invoke-Item "\\[FOLDER LOCATION]\EGScript43.vbs"
Write-Progress -Activity "Running Report2" -SecondsRemaining;
Invoke-Item "\\[FOLDER LOCATION]\EGScript43.vbs"
```

I need the 2nd report to run AFTER the 1st report is completed. I also need to see the progress of the reports.  Right now, the .bat will open an MS-DOT window with the progress timestamped. I need that same functionality in .ps1.

** Caveat, I'm not a programmer by trade.  I'm an analyst who was thrust into programming and have been mostly successful

Comment: Notwithstanding that I cannot see how `.bat` files have suddennly become a security issue, but not `.vbs` or `.ps1` files; I'm not sure if I understand your issue, because all you're doing in the `.bat` script is running an executable, `cscript.exe` with a file as an argument. The only thing that has changed is the shell, not those commands. `(Get-Date).ToString('T')` should provide an output of the time, but you don't appear to be doing that either.

Comment: Thanks Compo. I apologize for my lack of clarity.  My biggest issue isn't necessary the output of time and status, but that the reports are running simultaneously instead of consecutively.  Being able to see the status will alert me where the process is being hung up.

Comment: I've already told you that, the commands, `cscript //nologo //E:vbscript "\\[FOLDER LOCATION]\EGScript43.vbs"` and `cscript //nologo //E:vbscript "\\[FOLDER LOCATION]\PUMA_Check.vbs"` haven't changed, so just try them exactly as they are and you'll see that they run in sequence.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, You could practically copy paste the whole thing to a .ps1 and go from there. Bat commands will mostly work in powershell.

Comment: Thank you, Rohin. Yes, I see that the cScript will allow the reports to run consecutively.  Now, I just need to figure out the conversion of the "echo" command :) But the important part is answered

Comment: You don't need echo which is an alias for `Write-Output`, simply write numbers and text put in quotes. For a time stamp I'd use the format operator `"{0:T} running report x" -f (Get-Date)`

Comment: Sweet!  That worked.  Thanks @LotPings